# Walking through json mixed arrays and objects with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, iterator

I need walking trought json mixed arrays and objects.

I try, but get a [ErrorException] Array to string conversion

```
$epoJson = json_decode($json, true);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($epoJson), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD) as $key => $value) {
   echo 'My node ' . $key . ' with value ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

NOTE: I don't need a `echo`, `var_dump` or other , of course... I need iterate for put other code for work with values... code echo it's only for visualize problem... if I used `echo`ot's for simple question: if `$value`, it's not string...

Try search some examples or libraries for walk on json mixed but not get anything.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bd4fbc5e43ed439add7d4ba497b830d498ce4ac

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code 100% working:

**Note:** `$value` is array not string

```
<?php

$epoJson = json_decode($epoJson, true);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($epoJson), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD) as $key => $value) {
   //echo 'My node ' . $key . ' with value ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
    echo $key.'<br />';
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($value); // $value is array not string
    echo '<hr />';
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't need a var_dump or print $value. I ask for iterate on complex json with arrays and objects mixed.

Answer (score 1):

After looking for a good time, I realized that something was wrong, because I tried to validate when it was an object.

Remember that Laravel has a helper that does more or less what I want, at least depth

It traverses a multidimensional array with or without objects and converts it into a one-dimensional array.

Just what I needed.

```
/**
     * Flatten a multi-dimensional associative array with dots.
     *
     * @param  array   $array
     * @param  string  $prepend
     * @return array
     */
    public static function dot($array, $prepend = '')
    {
        $results = [];

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) && ! empty($value)) {
                $results = array_merge($results, static::dot($value, $prepend.$key.'.'));
            } else {
                $results[$prepend.$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $results;
    }
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9d8b0c293901325829219f5c03d655748802109